# cross platform usb module for python?

Tags: python, usb

I was interested in doing some cross platform work with a usb device in python, any tips or recommendations on modules that can do this type of thing?

I've looked around SF and googlecode without a lot of luck.

thanks!

ct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PyUSB](http://pyusb.berlios.de/) is what you are looking for. it is a wrapper around libusb which works on linux and was ported on Windows.

Comment: is there something that doesn't require an external usb dep (like libusb)?

Comment: i don't know of any. libusb (or any equivalent, like openusb) is a necessary evil since you need something like a device driver to write through the USB port, and you will not write such low-level stuffs in python.

Comment: @Adrien, one could presumably write to the Windows APIs using ctypes, which is now standard in Python.

Comment: @Peter: of course... but since some part of the code might end up in the kernel, i am quite sure the python interpreter will not fit there. (however, i don't know if something like libusb lies entirely in user space or have any kernel code)

Comment: I also noticed there's a linux variant: code.activestate.com/recipes/576834

Comment: @Adrien, I'm not sure what you mean about "interpreter will not fit there".  Are you suggesting it wouldn't be possible to write it with ctypes, or simply that it might be inadvisable?

Comment: @peter: i mean that i don't think it is a nice idea to execute a python program (with it's full-blown interpreter) in kernel space. some actions which are part of the initialization of the interpreter may be forbidden in kernel space. also, this might pose a security threat since any python module could then execute in the kernel...

Comment: @Adrien, okay, understood.  I would have thought that any such interface available through OS APIs that are reachable by ctypes would by definition execute in user space.  I suppose I'm wrong about that for Linux, though probably not where Windows is concerned.

Comment: libusb is 100% user space and operates against device files representing the USB devices in the UNIX family. On Windows, libusb can use one out of several drivers to access the USB device, typically WinUSB. A Python wrapper for WinUSB can be used instead, but you'd lose on portability.